# Connection string and variables in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS package creation.
I have created a SSIS package. But facing with two questions now

1. The package would be imported to SQL server and from SQL server it would connect with another system using connection string. In the connection string the password must be encrypted also I need to have the connection string dynamic since this package would run in different environments. Is it possible to decrypt the password on triggering the SQL job?
2. The package has variables in it, is it possible to pass values for those variables while starting the job using the T-SQL query EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job or is there any other way to pass values while triggering the SQL job

Comment: You cannot pass variables/parameters to agent jobs, no. If you need to run a task and pass variables/parameter to it, an Agent Job is not what you want.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the alternative to agent job to achieve the same

Comment: Create a procedure with parameters and execute that as and when you need it.

Comment: why you don't use Environment?

Answer (score -1):

first you must Made a connection in SSDT Project that better connection in Project LEvel

then you can made Environment in SSIS Catalog

then you can Set connection based on Environment Operation and decrypt the
password

example:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/